# ¿ Cómo podría implementar en un archivo CSV un diccionario en python?

Tags: python, csv, diccionarios

primera = {}

> Las keys y los values vienen mediante un input(no pongo todo el código porque es muy largo. Añadiré la función que está dentro de una clase.He de decir que el input del usuario se registra en un diccionario.
> Lo que me interesaría hacer es los datos de ese diccionario pasarlos a un archivo CSV.

```
primera = {}
pr= []

def mostrar_equipo(self):
    print("Los equipos son : ")

    for i in self.primera.keys():
        print("ID: " + str(i))
        print("Nombre: " + str(self.primera[i]))
    self.pr.append(self.primera)
    print(str(self.pr))
    for w in self.pr:
        print("ID: " + w["ID"])
        print("Nombre: " + str(w["nombre"]))
```

Comment: El cuerpo de tu pregunta no tiene relación con el titulo. Además es necesario que clarificas el problema/duda en específico.

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos csv no son apropiados para guardar diccionarios en general.

Analizemos este diccionario:

```
postulante = {
    "Nombre": "Juan", 
    "edad": 30, 
    "medallas": {"oro": 2, "plata":5, "bronce":10}, 
    "idiomas":["español", "inglés", "francés"]
    }
```

Este diccionario es una mezcla de todo tipo de valores. Tiene strings, enteros, listas y otros diccionarios.

Lo puedes guardar en formato .csv con una sola instruccion usando pandas:

```
pd.DataFrame([postulante]).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

El archivo resultante queda asi:

```
Nombre,edad,idiomas,medallas
Juan,30,"['español', 'inglés', 'francés']","{'oro': 2, 'plata': 5, 'bronce': 10}"
```

Los problemas saltan a la vista: las listas y diccionarios se guardaron como un solo string. Reconstruir el objeto original a partir de este csv va a ser díficil.

**Formato JSON**

La alternativa es guardar el diccionario en formato JSON, que tiene el beneficio de ser intercambiable con programas escritos en otros lenguajes.

Con JSON, sería así:

```
with open("out.json", "w") as out:
    out.write(json.dumps(postulante))
```

lo que produce este archivo:

```
{"Nombre": "Juan", "edad": 30, "medallas": {"oro": 2, "plata": 5, "bronce": 10}, "idiomas": ["espa\u00f1ol", "ingl\u00e9s", "franc\u00e9s"]}
```

Aquí, a diferencia del csv, los diccionarios y las listas están representadas correctamente, y los caracteres especiales escritos en unicode.

Leamos de vuelta ese .json y veamos que se obtiene:

```
with open("out.json", "r") as inn:
    s = inn.readline()
    post = json.loads(s)
    print(postulante)
    print(post)
```

produce

```
{'Nombre': 'Juan', 'edad': 30, 'medallas': {'oro': 2, 'plata': 5, 'bronce': 10}, 'idiomas': ['español', 'inglés', 'francés']}
{'Nombre': 'Juan', 'edad': 30, 'medallas': {'oro': 2, 'plata': 5, 'bronce': 10}, 'idiomas': ['español', 'inglés', 'francés']}
```

O sea, el diccionario original *postulante* quedo igual al diccionario leido, *post*.

Comment: Se podría usar JSON en POO?. Quiero decir, el proyecto está realizado con clases. Llevo poco tiempo con Python. Pero supongo que para poder aplicarlo debería usar el (self) ... por ejemplo en self .postulante. Igual me equivoco

Comment: @Daniel. Si x es un objeto de una clase cualquiera, lo puedes salvar en principio guardando el diccionario, asi: `ser = json.dumps(x.__dict__)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios. Al Final he podido resolverlo de otra forma... Gracias